# How to align multiple equation using tcolorbox in latex enviroment for Rmarkdown

Tags: r, equations

I have the following latex inside Rmarkdown:

```
\begin{tcolorbox}

\begin{equation}
   \sigma =  \beta_{0}                                                               
   \label{eq:Model0}
\end {equation}
\begin{equation}
   \sigma =  \beta_{0} + \beta_{1}K + \beta_{2}K^2 
  \label{eq:Model1}
\end {equation}
\begin{equation}
    \sigma = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1}K + \beta_{2}K^2 + \beta_{3}(T-t) +   \beta_{5}K(T-t)                 \label{eq:Model2}
\end {equation}
\begin{equation}
    \sigma = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1}K + \beta_{2}K^2 + \beta_{3}(T-t) + \beta_{4}(T-t)^2 + \beta_{5}K(T-t)
   \label{eq:Model3}
\end {equation}

\end{tcolorbox}
```

I want a box with these multiple equations, which one getting its own number (this is the reason for begining and ending 3 different eq environments) **AND all equations aligned to the left**.

How to define the alignment by the above latex?

I saw some reference for using `align`from `\usepackage{amsmath}` and then putting the `&` in the anchor for the alignment (e.g: "="),  but also saw some advices for avoiding such package in Rmarkdown environment.

Comment: hi @ialm tks! `eqnarray`worked ok.

Comment: `eqnarray` should never be used, it is heavily flawed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not use R markdown, however check of it documentation show, that in its use is not difference to between standard equation. So you can use `align`

```
\begin{tcolorbox}
\vspace{-\baselineskip}% <-- to remove extra vertical space
    \begin{align}
\sigma & = \beta_{0}      \label{eq:Model0}   \\
\sigma & = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1}K + \beta_{2}K^2
                        \label{eq:Model1}   \\
\sigma & = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1}K + \beta_{2}K^2 + \beta_{3}(T-t) + \beta_{5}K(T-t)
                        \label{eq:Model2}   \\
\sigma & = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1}K + \beta_{2}K^2 + 
                     \beta_{3}(T-t) + \beta_{4}(T-t)^2 + \beta_{5}K(T-t)
                        \label{eq:Model3}
    \end{align}
\end{tcolorbox}
```

if you like to have equation aligned ad `=` or `gather`, if you like to have equations centered:

```
\begin{tcolorbox}
\vspace{-\baselineskip}% <-- to remove extra vertical space
    \begin{gather}
\sigma = \beta_{0}      \label{eq:Model0}   \\
\sigma = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1}K + \beta_{2}K^2
                        \label{eq:Model1}   \\
\sigma = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1}K + \beta_{2}K^2 + \beta_{3}(T-t) + \beta_{5}K(T-t)
                        \label{eq:Model2}   \\
\sigma = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1}K + \beta_{2}K^2 + 
                     \beta_{3}(T-t) + \beta_{4}(T-t)^2 + \beta_{5}K(T-t)
                        \label{eq:Model3}
    \end{gather}
\end{tcolorbox}
```

Note: vertical spacing in `amsmath` or (better) `mathtools` math environments and ordinary `equation` environment is different!. Consequently, before `align` and `gather` I suggest to add `\vspace{-\baselineskip}` if before equations equations isn't text.

**Edit:** Another possible way to change distance between equation and `tcolorbox` is set vertical spaces before and after equation (as pointed John Kormylo in his comment) to zero. With this option the complete, compilable code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{tcolorbox}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}% for show only tcolorbox
\PreviewEnvironment{tcolorbox}
    \setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}
\abovedisplayskip=0pt% <--- remove vertical space above align
\belowdisplayskip=0pt% <--- remove vertical space below align
%\vspace{-1\baselineskip} %<--- original solution
    \begin{align}
\sigma & = \beta_{0}      \label{eq:Model0}   \\
\sigma & = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1}K + \beta_{2}K^2
                        \label{eq:Model1}   \\
\sigma & = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1}K + \beta_{2}K^2 + \beta_{3}(T-t) + \beta_{5}K(T-t)
                        \label{eq:Model2}   \\
\sigma & = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1}K + \beta_{2}K^2 +
                     \beta_{3}(T-t) + \beta_{4}(T-t)^2 + \beta_{5}K(T-t)
                        \label{eq:Model3}
    \end{align}
\end{tcolorbox}
    \end{document}
```

Which gives the same result as the first suggestion:

[image]

Comment: \abovedisplayskip=0pt and \belowdisplayskip=0pt also works.  The changes should be local to tcolorbox.

Comment: hi @JohnKormylo !! Thanks a lot! Yes, the `\vspace{-\baselineskip}` helped a lot too. Appreciated your attention!

Comment: @FábioSalles,do answer solve your problem? You can stick with equations, however they are not possible to align at `=`, but with with them is no problem with vertical spacing. And local changing of `amsmath` can become tricky, for example if you have more math environments and text between them ...

Comment: @Zarko, yes! it solved. Tks!

Comment: @FábioSalles, glad to hear this! Than you can upvote and accept answer  :-). Happy TeX-ing

Comment: @Zarko, sorry about that ! And thanks for the advice! New for me ;-)