# Correct vertical spacing correction for AMS multline within tcolorbox?

Tags: amsmath, tcolorbox, multline

My objective is to put a `tcolorbox` around one or more AMS `multline` environment(s).  However, there is extra space above the first equation.  Presumably I'm running into an issue like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/386258/too-much-space-above-align-environment-if-very-little-text-prior-to-it?rq=1).

I have not found a solution that addresses this situation directly (most seem to address `align` in `tcolorbox`es such as [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300434/equations-in-tcolorbox-vertical-alignment)).  One solution addresses it indirectly [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/288535/how-to-align-multiple-equation-using-tcolorbox-in-latex-enviroment-for-rmarkdown) and if I use `-6pt` I can get somewhat even vertical alignment.  I couldn't find a good way to set this via variable (e.g., `\baselineskip`).

I have also experimented with `empheq` but could not get it to behave in the desired way.

My questions:

1. Is there a better way to handle a `tcolorbox` around an AMS `multline` directly?
2. If not, is there a better way to do what I've done either by either setting up a custom `tcolorbox` to always include the "displayskips" and/or not having to hard code the `abovedisplayskip` value?

A MWE is shown below; my real equation is quite complicated and requires a `multline` (I'd **much** rather not try to use an alternative environment because of the amount of equation number management I would need to do in my write up).

**Edit to clarify:**

I want to emphasize the equations I put inside the box relative to the progression leading up to them and those that follow. So, I want the `tcolorbox` to respect the typical intra- and inter-paragraph line spacing and not act as an equation but then within the `tcolorbox` to have even vertical alignment.

---

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

An example \texttt{multline} formula is:

\begin{tcolorbox}
  \begin{multline}
    f(x) = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4\\
    + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9\\
    + 10.
  \end{multline}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image: Problematic Layout]

---

MWE with workaround:

```
...
\begin{tcolorbox}
  \abovedisplayskip=-6pt
  \belowdisplayskip=0pt
  \begin{multline}
...
```

[image: Fixed Layout via Workaround]

Comment: what about `\begin{tcolorbox}\vspace{-\baselineskip}\begin{multline}...\end{tcolorbox}`. Notice that I accidentally typed  `\begin{tcolorbox}\vspace{—\baselineskip}\begin{multline}...` which gives amusing unexpected result.

Comment: @jfbu, This causes the space at the top to be larger than below as I noted in my question.

Comment: it is matter of taste, just compare with not using the `tcolorbox` at all and directly `An example \texttt{multline} formula is:  \begin{multline}...`. The space above equation is very much the same (I did not measure) as when there is an extra `\begin{tcolorbox}\vspace{-\baselineskip}...`)

Comment: @jfbu Yes, it's a matter of taste but also a matter of vertical alignment.  I want a boxed multiline equation with even vertical alignment and spacing.  To not achieve that doesn't achieve the objective regardless of taste.

Comment: OK, but did you look at how it comes out without any tcolorbox? what you call "even vertical alignment and spacing" is not clear, else the amsmath creator would have not designed it this way.

Comment: @jfbu Yes I did.  However, I want to emphasize the equations I put inside the box relative to the progression leading up to them and those that follow.  So, I want the tcolorbox to respect the typical intra- and inter-paragraph line spacing and not act as an equation but then within the tcolorbox to have even vertical alignment.  Sorry that I didn't include these details in my original question.

Comment: I must correct what I said: the `-\baselineskip` suggestion is not so good approximation (it never was said to be exact), there is still noticeable more space than in non-tcolorbox context. Something like `-6mm` is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was  testing the `\useshortskip` command  from `nccmath`, and noticed that simply loading  the package seems to solve the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, nccmath}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

An example \texttt{multline} formula is:

\begin{tcolorbox}
  \begin{multline}
    f(x) = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4\\
    + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9\\
    + 10.
  \end{multline}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 indeed millimeter grid as in my answer seems to indicate this does it in the sense of achieving same vertical spacing as without tcolorbox. I do not know the details of tcolorbox, does it compensate its frame rule etc..., so it might also be quite a coincidence that this achieves same as in my answer (better than my answer), i.e. same vspacing as without presence of tcolorbox.

Comment: @Bernard, Excellent, this worked quite well; however, before loading nccmath I had to `\let\nr\relax\usepackage{nccmath}` because it conflicted with another package's definition.  I leave this comment future readers.

Comment: Oh! Where is it defined other than nccmath (I never used the  nccmath version anyway)?

Comment: @Bernard, I'm not sure and I didn't search for it.  This is for my dissertation that loads a *lot* of packages, so hunting down the error would take much longer than fixing it.

Comment: @Bernard `\nr` is defined in  `loops` and in `ltxtools-base`.

Comment: @jfbu, Thanks for doing the detective work.  Interesting that I don't load either of those packages directly; however, something else certainly may.

Comment: @JoelKulesza maybe explanation is to be found elsewhere, because simple grepping did not give me other package loading `loops` or `ltxtools-base`. You can exclude they are loaded by examining log, and it is faster with `\listfiles` in preamble as the log will contain a summary of all loaded files.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the key `ams nodisplayskip`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

An example \texttt{multline} formula is:
\begin{tcolorbox}[ams nodisplayskip]
  \begin{multline}
    f(x) = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4\\
    + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9\\
    + 10.
  \end{multline}
\end{tcolorbox}

An example \texttt{multline} formula is:
\begin{tcolorbox}
  \begin{multline}
    f(x) = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4\\
    + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9\\
    + 10.
  \end{multline}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It seems like this has the same effect as what @jfbu suggested, removing the baseline skip.  Is there a reason why the space above the multline is slightly larger than below?

Answer (score 0):

In order to empirically determine the needed correction (expecting it to remain applicable of course for other multline things), I used the device of a millimeter grid. Roughly, one needs `-6mm` to recover the same vertical spacing as in absence of tcolorbox. I understand from OP this is still too much, then one only needs to increase the `6mm`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\def\mygraphpaper{% copied/adapted from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/311407/4686
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[line width=.4pt,draw=black!20] (0,0) grid[step=1mm] (\paperwidth,\paperheight);
    \draw[line width=.4pt,draw=red!30] (0,0) grid[step=10mm] (\paperwidth,\paperheight);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{eso-pic}% has a grid option but not easily customizable

\AddToShipoutPictureFG{\AtPageLowerLeft{\mygraphpaper}}
% advantage to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/311407/4686 is that
% a single compilation is needed.

\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}

An example \texttt{multline} formula is:
  \begin{multline}
    f(x) = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4\\
    + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9\\
    + 10.
  \end{multline}

An example \texttt{multline} formula is:
\begin{tcolorbox}
\vspace{-6mm}
  \begin{multline}
    f(x) = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4\\
    + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9\\
    + 10.
  \end{multline}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In both cases the distance between baseline above and bottom of `x` in `f(x)` appears to be a bit less than `9mm`. One could also examine log output of  `\showoutput`... to be more precise.